# GCC's UTF-8 output displays incorrectly in Eclipse's build console

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, utf-8

I am using Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), Win7 SP1 and gcc 5.2.1 (for Cortex architecture, from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). When I try to compile C code encoded in UTF-8 (with BOM), gcc output appears in ANSI, incorrectly of course. My workspace and project have default encoding set to UTF-8.

Adding gcc switch `-finput-charset=UTF-8` doesn't change anything.

For sample code (in C):

```
#error some code here /* diacritics in comment żółćąę */
```

I get the following result in Eclipse's build console:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wextra -Wchar-subscripts -Werror=implicit -finput-charset=UTF-8 -g -ggdb3 -fverbose-asm -Wa,-ahlms=./out/logbook_entry_ext2.lst -pipe  -MD -MP -MF ./out/logbook_entry_ext2.d -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -I . -Itests/aceunit/ -Itests/ -Itests/inc/ logbook_entry_ext2.c -o out/logbook_entry_ext2.o

logbook_entry_ext2.c:32:2: error: #error some code here
 #error some code here /* diacritics in comment ĹĽĂłĹ‚Ä‡Ä…Ä™ */
```

Files encoded in ANSI (cp1250 in case of my locale - Central European languages) appear correctly.

The same applies to Eclipse's parsers (e.g. 'Problems' window - encoding is broken there in similar way).

I'm sure someone has overcome this problem, because it's silly to use ANSI encoding in 21st century, however most discussions one can google are about encoding strings and identifiers, which are not the case here.

EDIT: My exact question is how to solve this problem in Eclipse, e.g. by changing encoding of Eclipse's build console. Unfortunately I haven't found such setting so far (only for debug consoles).

Answer (score 1):

[ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) isn't an encoding, it's an organization.  perhaps you meant [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) ?  either way, that's probably not the issue.

you said your system locale is set to [Windows 1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) (codepage 1250).  that's really the problem here: you're attempting to use UTF-8 content in an incompatible encoding.

the [mojibake](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) you've shown there suggests that's the real problem.  if you take "żółćąę" and convert that byte sequence from a CP-1250 to UTF-8 encoding, you end up with "ĹĽĂłĹ‚Ä‡Ä…Ä™".  the [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) utility can be used to confirm this:

```
$ iconv -t UTF-8 -f CP1250 <<<'żółćąę'
ĹĽĂłĹ‚Ä‡Ä…Ä™
```

i imagine when Eclipse launches a [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM) shell to run tools (like gcc),  it uses your native locale (CP-1250).  so feeding it UTF-8 content would corrupt things.

the easy answer (imo) is to use UTF-8 everywhere instead of any Windows-specific encoding (like CP-1250).  Windows defines this as CP-65001.

Comment: I know WHAT is the problem, so I asked HOW can I resolve it. You reformulated my question, but didn't anwer it. I wrote, that I already use UTF-8 everywhere, but either gcc prints out or Eclipse interprets its output as an ancient ASCII (commonly yet incorrectly called "ANSI", e.g. in Notepad++ - you're right). And Windows uses Unicode mostly everywhere, cp1250 is locale chosen for programs which do NOT support Unicode, you can't use UTF-8 there.

Comment: i don't think gcc is wrong, either in its input or its output.  if you have CP-1250 set as your default, then see my section about command shell behavior.  if the command shell is running in CP-1250, then UTF-8 output from gcc will get corrupted in the way described.

Comment: Mike, I already know, that command shell is running cp1250, I'm familiar with this rubbish you call mojibake (it appears often on systems with non-ISO8859-1 locale). My question is how to solve this problem in Eclipse, e.g. by changing encoding of Eclipse's build console. I haven't found such setting so far (only for debug consoles).

Comment: i don't think you can have it both ways -- eclipse is either utf-8 sane or cp1250 insane.  if you just want to hack your system so the command tool is utf-8 sane, then there are many such posts in SO already on that topic.  search for "windows command unicode" or such.  perhaps `chcp 65001` will help.  i haven't run Windows in a long time ;).